# Algorithm for MST connecting a subgraph

Tags: algorithms, minimum-spanning-tree

I already know how to find the MST of a connected graph. This MST will have the least total weight and will connect **all** nodes in the graph.

However, this is a problem I have to deal with:

> Given a weighted graph $G=\{V,E\}$ and one of its subgraph $H$. Find a subset $E'$ of $E$ such that
>
> - If we clear out every edge outside of $E'$, $H$ is still connected.
> - The total weight of $E'$ is lowest possible.
>
> Note that $E'$ may contain edges that don't join two vertices in $H$, and any two vertices in $H$ may not necessarily be joined by an edge.

It is little different from the MST problem.

Firstly I thought that I only have to run MST algorithm in $H$, but I later found that this only work if any two vertices of $H$ is joined by an edge, not a series of edges.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: " may be unconnected". However, "If we clear out every edges outside of ′,  is still connected." Anyway, $H$ is connected initially, isn't it?

Comment: @Apass.Jack I think I rephrase the question wrongly, and I tried to edit it. Please let me know if my question is still unclear, and I will make it clearer. Thank you very much!

Comment: "I only have to run MST algorithm in , but I later found that this only work if any two vertices of  is joined by an edge, not a series of edge". Since $H$ is connected, you can run an MST algorithm on $H$ to get $T$. Let $E'=E\setminus T$, as you planned.

Comment: @Apass.Jack But I think using, for example, Kruskal's algorithm, only allows me to run on edges that connected two vertices in $H$. If I want to run MST on $H$, I think I have to change many edges like `a--1--b--3--c` to `a--4--c`, and so the algorithm is not efficient anymore.

Comment: "Kruskal's algorithm only allows me to run **on edges that connected two vertices in $H$**." That is exactly what we wanted.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Could you please explain more? I don't think that may help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89762/discussion-between-apass-jack-and-joulev).

Comment: When you say that $H$ is a subgraph, do you mean that a problem instance might include edges in $H$?  If so is the intention that these edges must be kept (i.e., must be in $E'$)?  Or do you really mean that $H$ is simply a subset of the vertices in $G$?  My answer addresses the latter case, but it can be adapted to the former case in a simple way.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Steiner Tree problem, specifically the [Steiner Tree problem in graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem#Steiner_tree_in_graphs_and_variants): the vertices in $H$ are the terminals.  Unfortunately it's NP-hard, so it's very unlikely that a polynomial-time algorithm exists.

If $E$ describes a metric, then the minimum spanning tree on $H$ gives a 2-approximation.

Comment: If this is the right answer, then the problem should have been stated as "... Given a weighted graph $G=\{V,E\}$ and $H$ that is a subset of $V$...$H$ is still connected by the remaining edges".

Comment: @Apass.Jack: Right, my answer is only for the special case where $H$ contains only vertices and no edges.  But if the intention is that $H$ can contain edges, and that these must appear in $E'$, then my answer can be adapted simply: Before solving ST, add all edges in $H$ to $E'$, and merge the endpoints of these edges in $G$.